# SimpleDom Search Via plaintext Text

Tags: simple-html-dom

I am using "PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser" library and looking forward to find elements based on its text value (plaintext)

For example i need to find span element using its value "Red".

```
<span class="color">Red</span>
```

I was expecting bellow code to work but seems that it just replaces the value instead of searching it.

```
$brand = $html->find('span',0)->plaintext='Red';
```

I read Manual and also i tried to look in library code itself but was not able to find the solution, kindly advise if i am missing something or it is simply not possible to do via Simple Html DOM Parser.

P.S
Kindly note that i am aware of other ways like regex.

Answer (score 0):

Using `$html->find('span', 0)` will find the (N)th span where in this case n is zero.

Using `$html->find('span',0)->plaintext='Red';` will set the plaintext to `Red`

If you want to find the elements where the text is `Red` you could use a loop and omit the 0 to find all the spans.

For example, using [innertext](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual_api.htm) instead of plaintext:

```
$spansWithRedText = [];

foreach($html->find('span') as $element) {
    if ($element->innertext === "Red") {
        $spansWithRedText[] = $element;
    }
}
```

Comment: In other words simple dom doesn't support function to find element based on its text value (plaintext) correct ?

Comment: @GeorgeSamarguliani I could not find an example that did. In the [api docs](https://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.io/manual_api.htm) it states that find takes a `string $selector`